# Calculate mean and variance of a timed signal

Tags: variance, mean, signal-processing

I have a function rapresenting a signal, where x-axis are times and y-axis are signal volts. Signal seems to be sampled at 200Hz, even if for some "times" it have 199 samples and not 200 as expected.

Following is an example of my signal data (TIME - SIGNAL):

```
0 - 2.56
0.12325 - 2.58
0.134564 - 2.6233
...
1.2133 - 2.45
1.3425 - 2.56
...
```

For the second 0 I have 200 samples, and for second 1 I have 199 samples (and not 200 as expected).

My asks is: how to calculate mean and variance of the entire signal? My ask is due to the fact that normally I calculate the mean and variance without the "TIME" information. So, do I need to take care also about "time information", or not?

Comment: It depends on what properties of the signal "mean" and "variance" are intended to refer to.  Two alternatives are (1) properties of some assumed underlying probability distribution at any given time and (2) integrals (over time) of the signal and its squared difference from the mean.  Could you clarify?

Comment: hello @whuber , thank you for your fast reply. I can say that I need just to calculate mean and variance of the signal. There are no "time reference" in what I need to calculate. I was tempted to calculate the mean and the variance ignoring the time, as is usually done, but the difference of the samples between the various seconds made me doubt about it

Comment: The problem, as I tried to explain, is that "mean and variance of the signal" is not clear enough.  You need to help us understand what *you* mean by this phrase.